# Bootstrap classes to indent sub fields in a form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Example Site ->  http://env-1124382.jelastic.servint.net/restaurant/?timezone=Etc/GMT0

1. When you click on online ordering allowed, I like maximum order amount field to be nested to the right. M of Maxiumum should be straight under the checkbox. How do I do it with bootstrap?
2. When you click on add open close order times couple of times, you will notice there is no horizontal space between the boxes. I like it to be aligned like point 1. How do I do it with bootstrap?

Comment: in point 2 did you mean vertical space? are do you really want a separation between labels and inputs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do some small css stuff to do this..

For **pt. 1**, just build a class to margin the checkbox left...

```
.check-margin10 { margin-left:10px; /* Set as you wish */ }
```

Add it in:-

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" onclick="enableDisableOnlineOrderingOptions(this)" name="onlineOrderingAllowed" id="onlineOrderingAllowed" class="check-margin10">
```

Same as **pt. 2**,

```
.horizon-margin10 { margin-bottom:10px; /* Set as you wish */ }
```

add like this:-

```
<div id="MONDAY0" class="form-inline horizon-margin10">
```

Thanks...

Comment: Hi @AnantSajnani that's great, glad that we were able to help! If your question is answered now, please do ensure that you mark the correct answer (there's a tick icon alongside each answer - the relevant one just needs ticking). This ensures that people coming to the site in the future with a similar problem will be able to easily find the relevant answer too.